# "Merging" a straight line into a Gaussian curve

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, math, geometry, calculus

You can assume that the first image below is the original Gaussian curve. The second image is the desired output. I have these equations:

- Equation of each red line segment (let's call this the piecewise function *f(x)*)
- Equation of the Gaussian curve (*g(x)*)

I am trying to make an equation that can alter the Gaussian curve to match the curve in the second image. I have tried plotting *(f(x) + g(x)) / 2* (last image) but it doesn't do the trick. I have also tried using the red line segment on far right as the independent axis for plotting the right part of the curve but that leads to a huge discontinuity. Does anyone have any other ideas?

**Edit:** The third image shows what happens when I try linear interpolation.

[image: Actual Gaussian curve]

[image: Adjusted curve]

[image: Linear interpolation]

Comment: Do you want the derivatives to be continuous (and if so, how many)?

Comment: I just need derivative to be defined and the curve to be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Try to approximate your Gaussian curve with B-spline like, for example, it is done [here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~dfg/AndysSplineTutorial/BSplines.html). Since how to add points to a B-Spline (which is a generalization of Bezier Curves) is more clear you should be able to get the result you want.

Comment: I was trying to avoid approximating with Bezier curves but I since I haven't found any other solution yet and I have a deadline to meet, I think I'll go for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the math aspect of this, but as for the last part of you question (plotting the right part of the curve using the red axis), I'm thinking you could smooth the transition between the curve and the axis with quite a simple process:

```
plotPosition = curvePosition * (1 - t) + otherPosition * t;
```

"t" being a number between 0-1 (when t=0 plotPosition equals curvePosition, when t=1 plotPosition equals otherPosition), that way you can determine when and how you want the transition to happen. You can smooth it even further using some equation to determine the transition value over time (easing).

Comment: Linear interpolation leads to corners where the gradient of f(x) changes. If you set t to 0.5, this concept just transforms into *(f(x) + g(x)) / 2* which I already tried. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: The idea is to change t progressively along the path of the curve... so say you have t=0 during the whole curve, but when the diagonal axis starts, you slowly start increasing t until you end up with 1 at the end of the curve (you can use some easing equation to control the "shape" of the transition). I know it's not a valid mathematical answer, but it could help you to come up with one ;)